# re.search AND linking several conditions, python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a set that I want to search for multiple characters.
However, My function should return "true" if all conditions are met.
I would like to use "regular expressions", if possible.

A set can possibly be:

```
set_a = {'B', 'C', 'b', 'c'}
set_b = {'B', 'C', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd'}
set_c = {'A', 'G', 'D', 'F', 'b', 'e'}
...
```

My function to look for some characters look like:

```
if re.search("[a]", set_a) and re.search("[b]", set_a) and re.search("[c]", set_a):  
        return True
```

In further if queries I want to search for other characters.
I do not like the and-link between my expressions.
Is there a way to search for example for [a][b][c] in only one expression?
 I haven't found anything in the documentation or here, but I'm sure there is something quite simple. I'm a complete beginner. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the example I search for a b and c. My point is that I can make an AND link the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using `re.search()` for this, it's for searching for patterns in a string, not a list.

You can use the `all()` function:

```
if all(c in lit_list for c in "abc"):
    return True
```

Comment: Regarding your first sentence I believe the list is to be used to form the pattern that is used to match an arbitrary string.

Comment: That wasn't the impression I got. The list has 4 characters, but he's only searching for 3 of them with `re.search()`. And he said "I have a list I want to search".

Comment: my list can also look like: {'B', 'C', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd'}. Sometimes I want to search for two or more letters

Comment: I don't understand, how is that list different from the one you showed above? BTW, that's a `set`, not a `list`, a list would be `['B', 'C', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: If I didn't understand the question, you should edit the question to make it more clear, and show examples of other forms.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I've re-formulated my question.

Comment: Where do you have strings with two or more letters? I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression comprised of one positive lookahead for each character in the list:

```
/(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)/
```

You will need to use Python methods to form the regular expression. In Ruby this could be done as follows.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
s = list.each_with_object('') { |c,s| s << "(?=.*#{c})" }
  #=> "(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)"
Regexp.new(s)
  #=> /(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)/
```

I doubt that use of a regular expression is the best way to address the problem, but that’s a separate issue.

Comment: Thanky Cary, I do not understand your answer. I restated my question.